# Grails Package name wont change

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

I have started learning Grails and now familiarizing with configurations.
To change the default package name for my grails project i entered the following in
config.groovy

```
grails.project.groupId = com.grailspractice.nick
```

Then ,

```
grails create-controller testc
```

But the files are not being created in the package domain structure.
I get the following structure instead

```
Created file grails-app/controllers/testapp/TestcController.groovy
Created file grails-app/views/testc
Created file test/unit/testapp/TestcControllerSpec.groovy
```

Please tell me if i am missing anything else.
Also If I run my app using

```
grails run-app
```

Then the application runs fine, but if in a separate command window if i create a controller while the application is running i get the following error on my prompt where the app was running

```
grails error cannot get property on cache operation source null object
```

Is it an installation problem? Or have i messed up any configuration?

Comment: Make sure the group id is in quote. `grails.project.groupId = "com.grailspractice.nick"`

Comment: grails.project.groupId should have a value enclosed in double quotes. It's a string. Wrap your value in double quotes. grails.project.groupId = "com.grailspractice.nick"

Comment: Didnt work,   grails> create-controller testnew
| Created file grails-app/controllers/testapp/TestnewController
| Created file grails-app/views/testnew
| Created file test/unit/testapp/TestnewControllerSpec.groovy

Comment: Should add as an answer. @Alidad / Joshua Moore

Comment: Adding quotes didnt help. Still the same output. Do you want to see the entire config file?

Comment: Exit interactive mode, `clean` and then run command again.

Comment: Thanks!!That worked.I did clean , exit and again created controller. What about the second issue? The error message?

Comment: I don't normally do that. However, does the app use forked mode?

Comment: I am sorry,I do not know what forked mode is..This is my first time with grails. There is another issue I see..when i enter the application folder using cd appname...and just type in grails to get the grails prompt i get the erroe :1:1 fatal error premature end of file..is it normal?